# Is proof of concept a good thing to do in an internship?

Tags: software-industry, internship

I started my internship recently, in a software company. I joined this place assuming that I will be working on some solid tech stuff that they're already working on. But after joining, I was told to learn something new (which is totally fine) and produce a Proof of Concept (POC). At the end of the day, I want to show on my resume that I have done some pretty solid work in the internship. So will this POC thing be worthy on my resume? Please advise.

P. S. - I am sure they don't want me to be involved in the development process, hence they're giving me some random work.

Comment: It’s reasonable request

Comment: How is a proof of concept not solid development work? Sounds like you will be working on something that no one else and learning a lot along the way. That's great resume material.

Comment: "I am sure they don't want me to be involved in the development process, hence they're giving me some random work." - Except it is not random. They use a low cost additional ressource to validate an idea or approach they have. This is (a) part of the development process and (b) not random work. Both of your assumptions are wrong.

Comment: A proof of concept is what R&D does. The only reason you think this might be a bad idea is if you don't feel confident in your abilities. And yes, you're right. If you're too slow, or incompetent, maybe that's the reason they gave it to you, as a way to park you on the side so you don't do damage to the main project. However, if you're competent, it's a great opportunity!! If your project really becomes officially adopted, you will become invaluable to the company and anyone else who wants to hire you. And of course, in that scenario, it will be great for your resume also.

Comment: It really matters more what the proof of concept actually is, and maybe whether you want to work on production code in future, or go more into research.

Comment: I just spent 6 months working on a PoC for a major client. At the end of it, we signed a big contract. The CEO thinks it was worthy, and that's good enough for me,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many times if your proof of concept works out really well, it will be made into an official project.

In my internship, one other intern and I made a proof of concept, and it turned into an official project after we presented it to the president and the board. After that we were put in charge of the project with the lead tech as our advisor, and a senior engineer placed in to code review. It was a great learning experience, and it has served well as a talking point in interviews since then.

Even if the proof of concept doesn't work out, it doesn't really mean it was a waste. It would still be a good experience in itself to plan and try to create minimalized version of a project. That in itself would be a good thing  to talk about in an interview. If there is a technical reason why it wouldn't work, then you can explain how you found that reason.

Answer (score -1):

Internships themselves are essentially proofs of concept. You working on a proof of concept while the company is *proving you* is totally appropriate and can be a great way for you to develop skills and get some (semi) real world experience. It's likely better than many internships which often focus on menial work (filing, unimportant documentation, etc.)

In terms of your actual question,

> So will this POC thing be worthy on my resume?

As with just about any *"how will this look on my resume?"* question, it's hard to answer that without some context. What are you trying to achieve in your career? What sorts of positions will you be going after? What sorts of companies?

Instead of worrying how something will look, turn the "issue" into a benefit. Once you've thought about these questions (what sorts of positions at what sorts of employers), consider how your experience could be a benefit for those positions/companies, and then **word your resume to emphasize those aspects** of your experience.